# Update all views while UISlider is being changed

Tags: sprite-kit, uislider, scenekit

Hello I have a SCNScene with a sprite kit overlay. I also have a subview that contains just a UISlider. The Slider controls the value of one of the SKLabel nodes in the sprite kit overlay. However when I am moving the slider the label does not update. It only updates once I touch outside of the slider. So I am guessing that the SCNScene and the overlay don't update while my touches are in the subview and only update once I touch back to the main view. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

My project is in swift, but if you only know objective-c ill still gratefully take your answer and translate on my own.

SceneKit Code:

```
class MyMarbleScene: UIViewController {
var scene: SCNScene!
var sceneView: SCNView!
var hud : MyMarbleSpriteKit!


var cameraNode: SCNNode!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    // create a new scene
    scene = SCNScene()
    sceneView = SCNView()
    sceneView.frame = self.view.frame
    sceneView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.allZeros
    sceneView.scene = scene
    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = false
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = false
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    self.view = sceneView

    cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 20, z: 60)


    hud = MyMarbleSpriteKit(size: self.view.frame.size, game: self)
    sceneView.overlaySKScene = hud

    let frame = CGRectMake(10.0, self.view.frame.height*0.5, 180.0, 10.0)
    let slider = UISlider(frame: frame)
    slider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderValueChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    slider.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    slider.minimumValue = 1.0
    slider.maximumValue = 10.0
    slider.continuous = true
    slider.value = 5

    self.view?.addSubview(slider)


}

func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var currentValue = Int(sender.value)
    println("\(currentValue)")
    self.hud.updateLabel(currentValue)
}
```

}

SpriteKit code

```
class MyMarbleSpriteKit: SKScene {


var myScene: MyMarbleScene!


var SensLabelTwo = SKLabelNode()


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

}

init(size: CGSize, game:MyMarbleScene) {
    super.init(size: size)
    myScene = game


    let SensLabel = SKLabelNode()
    SensLabel.text = "Marble Sensitivity:"
    SensLabel.fontName = "AvenirNext-HeavyIta"
    SensLabel.fontSize = 40
    SensLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    SensLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.Top
    SensLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 170, y: size.height-20)
    self.addChild(SensLabel)



    SensLabelTwo.text = "5"
    SensLabelTwo.fontName = "AvenirNext-HeavyIta"
    SensLabelTwo.fontSize = 60
    SensLabelTwo.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    SensLabelTwo.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.Top
    SensLabelTwo.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: size.height-80)
    self.addChild(SensLabelTwo)

}

func updateLabel(text: Int){

    println("helllo")

    SensLabelTwo.text = String(format:"%i", text)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

Comment: can you show the code us the code?

Comment: see edit for the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 2D scene is not automatically refreshed when it's modified.
You will have to wait for the 3D scene to be redisplayed first. This happens when 3D animations or actions are running or when `playing` is set to `YES`. Alternatively, you can manually request a refresh with `-[SCNView setNeedsDisplay]`.